# How can i fix this error in Next js framework?

Tags: reactjs, web, next.js, deployment

```
import {Button, Checkbox, Input, Textarea, useDisclosure} from "@nextui-org/react";
import {Modal, ModalContent, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter} from "@nextui-org/modal";
```

Every time i run gives this error when i reload:
[image]

this is the error in vs code terminal

```
  13 |
 ⨯ src\app\page.tsx (10:49) @ useDisclosure
 ⨯ TypeError: (0 , _nextui_org_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.useDisclosure) is not a function
    at Home (./src/app/page.tsx:20:105)
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
digest: "3081696306"
   8 |
   9 | export default function Home() {
> 10 |   const {isOpen, onOpen, onClose} = useDisclosure();
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your import from `@nextui-org/react` not from `@nextui-org/modal`  :

```
import {Modal, ModalContent, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Button, useDisclosure...} from "@nextui-org/react";
```

Comment: yes, i did it , stiil the same issue

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `'use client'` on top of the file to make it work.